# Can I change the padding programmatically on the Widget?

Tags: java, android

Can I do something in the `public void onUpdate` widget method to change the `padding` of the `textView1` on my Widget?

I know how to change `textView.Text` using - `RemoteViews views` and `views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1`etc.
One man said, I can't use `RemoteViews` to change the `padding` on the Widget. So what can I do, and how? I must change the `padding` programmatically. Padding will be changeable.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried ?

```
yourTextView.setPadding(60, 0, 0, 0);
```

EDIT

If you are developing for API level > 16, you may use the following method to set a left padding for instance:

```
views.setViewPadding(R.id.widget_item, 30, 0, 0, 0);
```

change the 30 value to whatever you want

EDIT 2

**Take this info**

You cannot do this in lower SDK . If you look at the android source the setPadding method is not marked with "@RemotableViewMethod" which allows it's value to be set by the RemoteViews object. The only hack we found was to use a different layout.

Comment: its Widget, not normal Activity, so to change antyting probably I must use other, longer methods like RemoteViews or something else.

Comment: Edited with proposition

Comment: thx but do you know other methods for lower SDK version like 10 or something? Because lvl 16 is so high for many smartphones

Comment: Edited with explanation about lower sdk version

Comment: thanks for repling, so my files are -> Main.java (widget code) + layout1.xml (widget ImageView + TextView1) and i have the second file settings.java + layout_settings.xml (with 2 buttons to set padding). In the file settings.java I have implemented OnClickListener for Buttons, which code can I use now to set textView1 (on the layout1.xml) padding?

Comment: btw. and forgive me pls for "no" Vote_UP for your posts, i dont have required 15 rep points for this

Comment: this one apply to your Views : views.setViewPadding(R.id.widget_item_news_publishedDate_text, 30, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: do you have Team Viewer program?

Comment: widget_item is your TextView

Comment: @ Nadir B do you have 5 minutes for me to download PORTABLE version and connect to my computer and show me what to do if i want use minSDK version 8 or something? :D http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerPortable.zip

Comment: unfortunately right now I can't use it or install it

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/dFLZ9Ga.jpg So my widget basic files = one .java file + one .xml file for widget (there is textView1 + ImageView). Next two files (one .java file + one .xml file) = settings window. And on that settings window i have 3 Buttons, on the screen you see the code for first Button (onClick method). Can i use any code there to set the PADDING of the textView1 on the my widget .xml layout?

Comment: and if possible i want to use android:minSdkVersion="8"

Comment: well to use minSDk of 8 you simply can't on widgets try creating your own custom TextView, for what you asked for you need to get a reference to your xml file